# Firebase : Firestore not updating data in Cloud Function's scheduled function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a very weird experience here, my scheduled function will make an update to a document every 12:00 am and it works, however nothing has change on the document.

```
exports.updatePrediksiData = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *')
    .timeZone('Asia/Manila') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
    .onRun((context) => {

        //This will be run every day at 12:00 AM

        return updatePrediction()
            .catch(error => {
                return db.collection("Issues").doc(new Date().getTime().toString()).set({
                    error: error.message,
                    log: "updatePrediction failed to update prediction data."
                });
            });

    });

function updatePrediction() {

    const dateFormat = require('dateformat');

    dateFormat.i18n = {
        dayNames: [
            'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat',
            'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'
        ],
        monthNames: [
            'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec',
            'Januari', 'Februari', 'Maret', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Agustus', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Desember'
        ],
        timeNames: [
            'a', 'p', 'am', 'pm', 'A', 'P', 'AM', 'PM'
        ]
    };

    var genVal = getPrediksi();

    const currentDate = new Date();

    //Tuesday and Friday is not included
    if (currentDate.getDay() === 2 || currentDate.getDay() === 5)
        genVal = "----";

    return db
        .collection("Prediksi")
        .doc("Togel")
        .set({
            date: dateFormat(new Date().getTime(), "dd mmmm yyyy"),
            value: genVal
        })
        .then(result => {
            console.log("Updating prediction is success.");
            return true;
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error("Failed updating the prediction.", error);
            throw new Error(error);
        });

}
```

The expected new data of 'value' field will be "----" since its Friday, but nothing has change even the date.

[image: Screenshot showing it is success]

Here as you can see it says success.

[image: The issue]

But as you can see no changes has been applied, at first I thought it is with Firebase Firestore Rule but functions are with Admin SDK where rules is not being applied. What went wrong here? I am using Node js 10 here, and so far this is the first time I have this issue with writing on Firestore while other functions works perfectly fine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm unclear what this code is supposed to do.  `updatePrediction` doesn't do anything except assign some values which are never used.  Your call to `set()` just writes some strings to a document.

Comment: @DougStevenson as you have said I call `set()` to change the old field values but the `date` field is still Nov 19 not Nov 20 and the `value` field is suppose to be now "----" since it is Friday.

Comment: Your call to set() is writing two fields: "error" and "log" to a document whose ID is based on a date.  I don't see any of that in the screenshot here.

Comment: @DougStevenson please check the code `updatePrediction` then check the screenshots. Just ignore the logging of error since as you can see there is no error and it says success. By the way I am testing it again and it seems the dates in Cloud Function is based on US since I am still getting Nov 19 value which is not correct here in Asia.

Comment: hi, can you explain how the function gets the document to be processed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I confirmed that this is the issue with `Date` object, I changed the timezone to my target audience as a fix like this `new Date(new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "Asia/Jakarta" }))`. At first I tried to move the function region as I thought that will fix the problem and will move the timezone, well it is not.